# How does this vector work?

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to understand a code here.

```
f = open('/Users/nk/Vocab.txt','r')
vocab_temp = f.read().split()
f.close()
col = len(vocab_temp)
print("Training column size:")
print(col)

row = run('cat '+'/Users/nk/X_train.txt'+" | wc -l").split()[0]
print("Training row size:")
print(row)
matrix_tmp = np.zeros((int(row),col), dtype=np.int64)
print("Train Matrix size:")
print(matrix_tmp.size)

label_tmp = np.zeros((int(row)), dtype=np.int64)
f = open('/Users/nk/X_train.txt','r')
count = 0
for line in f:
    line_tmp = line.split()
    #print(line_tmp)
    for word in line_tmp[0:]:
        if word not in vocab_temp:
            continue
        matrix_tmp[count][vocab_temp.index(word)] = 1
    count = count + 1
f.close()
```

I understand that `col` is basically the word from the vocabulary and `row` is the textual data in the training set.
I also understand that in the `loop`, the code is actually checking if a word that exists in the vocabulary, exists in the train set or not. Can someone please explain me what does the line after `continue` tend to do?

Comment: It assigns `1` to an index in the matrix. That index is created by searching for the word in `vocab_temp` via the `index` method of that list.

Comment: Based on the code, it seems like a good guess that whoever wrote this code probably wanted `matrix_tmp[count][vocab_temp.index(word)] += 1` instead of the assignment statement that's in there now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matrix_tmp[count][vocab_temp.index(word)] = 1`
If you look into the code, the `count` increments by 1 every line. So the `matrix_tmp[count]` is a vector of words for each line.

Now, considering the `vocab_temp.index(word)`, you can see in the second line that the `vocab_temp` keeps the vector that results from `f.read().split()`.

The fact that it takes the index from the `vocab_temp`, it actually gets a position for the matrix (the index in matrix where your word `word` is located and sets it to 1 (word `word` occurred on the `index` position).